# How to diasable previous date in datetime picker in bootstrap datetimepicker js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, datetimepicker

I am Used date time picker in my file with bootstrap j query calender file.and i am try this function in JavaScript.`$(function() {$('#datepicker').datepicker({ maxDate: 0 });});`
But this function not working in my file. and if this function used in datepicker then this function work properly.so anyone can help me how to disable previous date in bootstrap date time picker calender.

Answer (score 0):

```
var minDate = new Date(); // Our minimum

$('.someSelector').datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function(ev){
    if (ev.date.valueOf() < minDate.valueOf()){

        /* Handle previous date */
        alert('Nope');
        // and eventually reset the date

        /* And this for later versions (just in case) */
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: this code working only date picker.but not working in date time picker. so please give another answer